# Why does Alexa session startup return error on first invocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

Has anyone ever experienced the first call to an AWS Lambda function failing on only the first request sent to Alexa? (Remote endpoint unavailable error) I have a custom skill that does not use account linking. I have some intent code that runs on an AWS Lambda service, and it only seems to be the first invocation of the skill after a prolonged period of inactivity that causes the problem. If I call the intent code with an utterance a second time after, the intent code will run properly. I'm wondering if there is an inactivity shutdown of the Lambda service when it is in a development environment, and it is reactivated when put to use again. Is this true?

Comment: I doubt it. Are you sure you are handling the launch intent properly? Have you tried to test your lambda locally, with tools like  BST (https://github.com/bespoken/bst)?

Comment: I am handling the onLaunch intent in the same manner as this: https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-js/tree/master/samples/helloWorld/src. I guess perhaps I am confused as to what constitutes "launch". You can say, "Alexa launch skill," and the launch intent code will be run (straightforward). You can also initiate the session by doing something like "Alexa ask skill to do something." This is the case I have seen the error. I have not tested the Launch case, and I will do that tomorrow. Thank you for the testing framework. I will check it out.